# Replace and remove a string via regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This is first time I am working with regex.

The string below

```
var value ="abc ltd as yes"
```

need to be change to

```
var value ="abc Limited"
```

I have the following code:

```
  public static string Attempt_Prefix_Removal( string prefix, string replacement, bool remove = false)
    {

        if (remove == true)
        {

            var yesy = $"(?<!prefix )" + prefix + ".*";

            var test = Regex.Replace(prefix.ToLower(), $"(?<!prefix )" + prefix + ".*", replacement );



        }

        var output = (remove == true) ? Regex.Replace(prefix.ToLower(), $"(?<!prefix )" + prefix + ".*", replacement) :  Regex.Replace(prefix.ToLower(), $"(?<!prefix )" + prefix + "", replacement);

        return output;


    }
```

the values that are passed to the method are

```
prefix ="ltd", replacement = "Limited" , remove = ture
```

after running the code the result is

```
abc Limited as yes
```

what do i need to change to get ride of `as yes` ??
thanks

Comment: [Like this?](https://regex101.com/r/1UxCSa/2)

Comment: What are the requirements? Replace `ltd` with `Limited` when ....? When? And remove what? `as yes` or the rest of the *string*? Or *line*? BTW, [I get `Limited` as output](http://ideone.com/osTGba).

Comment: Pretty weird that it's called prefix removal but it removes the "suffix". You can replace ltd with Limited and you can also replace as yes with Limited and you can also replace ltd as yes with Limited.

Comment: any time there is ltd replace it with limited and then ignore what come after it

Comment: Then try `Regex.Replace(s, $@"(?s)\b{prefix}\b.*", replacement)`. Or build the pattern like this - `$@"(?s)(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(prefix)}(?!\w).*"` and replace with `replacement.Replace("$", "$$")` to make it safer. Keep `.*` when `remove` is *true*, else discard it from the pattern.

Comment: Check http://ideone.com/xcwXum

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks the link help in the end it came like $@"((?<=^|\s|\^){value.ToLower()}(?=$|\s|){(postdelete == true ? ".*" : String.Empty)})|(.((?<=\(){value.ToLower()}(?=\))).{(postdelete == true ? ".*" : String.Empty)})";

Comment: Can some one tell me why does this question get  mark down ??

Comment: Ok,  I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may leverage this code:

```
var prefix ="ltd"; var replacement = "Limited";
var pat = $@"(?s)(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(prefix)}(?!\w){remove ? ".*" : string.Empty}";
return Regex.Replace(val, pat, replacement.Replace("$", "$$"));
```

See the [C# demo online](http://ideone.com/xcwXum)

The main points here are:

- `(?s)`   - will allow `.` match a newline (in case you will use `.*` in the pattern)
- `(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(prefix)}(?!\w)`  - the `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind will fail the match if the current location is preceded with a word char (you may further tweak the lookbehind pattern as per your requirements)
- `{remove ? ".*" : string.Empty}` - this will either append `.*` (if `remove` is *true*) or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
private string regexOp(string sentence, string word, string wordtoReplace, bool isRemove)
    {
        var retValue = sentence;
        if (isRemove)
        {
            var Pattern = "^.*?(?=" + word + ")";
            Match result = Regex.Match(sentence, @Pattern);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Value))
                retValue = result + wordtoReplace;
        }
        else
            retValue = Regex.Replace(sentence, word, wordtoReplace);

        return retValue;
    }
```

try this method, this will work as you expected with dynamic,
do not forget to mark it as answer if this really helped you,